# Implementation of protected / private inheritance in compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

If a class derives from another class like

```
class B{};
class D : private B{};
```

then I can not create derived class objects like:-

```
B* ptr = new D;
```

If I check the assembly difference of this code vs assembly code of class D deriving
from class B publically, I don't find any differnce.

Can anyone explain exactly how and at what stage the complier is differentiating between public / protected and private inheritance.

Comment: Which compiler are you asking about? Why do you care about the implementation of a specific compiler rather than semantics given to your code by the C++ standard?

Comment: I wonder: You write, correctly, that you cannot do this. But then you write about comparing assembler code. If it does not compile, what assembler code are you looking at?

Comment: @Rene, For comparing the assembly code, I am not creating the derived class object at all. Only compiling the code which have both the classes defined in file.

Comment: Inheretance is an abstraction of language, so implementation doesn't matter(like reference is constant pointer inside)

Comment: There is no difference in the code. There is a difference in the access control rules, which are enforced at compile time, not at runtime, *ergo* not in the object codel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler checks protection (public/private) in the frontend while parsing your code. Once it gets to the optimizer and code generation they are gone.

Comment: Usually. But information about what's private and public, in some form, needs to be present in the RTTI information so that `dynamic_cast` can fail when attempting to cast to something non-`public`. Also, during code generation the compiler has to ensure that data members declared with the same access level (originally in C++98 it was, within the cover of the same instance of an access specifier) are placed a strictly increasing addresses. So, this answer captures the main idea, but the details are thorny. ;-)

Comment: Well, I have to have breakfast etc. and do some things so I suggest you just research this, including by trying out code examples, and add the info.

Answer (score 0):

`private` means: "Can only be accessed from within the class or friends of the class"

Private inheritance is the same as public inheritance; but there are restrictions on which code that can access the fact that `D` is inherited from `B`. Since you can do all the same things with private inheritance as with public inheritance (but only in a limited scope), it makes sense that the two implemented in an identical way.

Your claim that you can't make derived classes with `B* ptr = new D;` is only true if you are not in the scope of `D`; for example, this works:

```
class B{};
class D : private B{
    public:
    void makeB() {
        B* ptr = new D;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler just parse the language and make sure that you do not break the rules.

It then goes on to produce some machine code (maybe via assembly language).

As long as you have not broke the rules of C++ it is free to do the implementation in machine code.

So at that stage private/public/protected or whatever does not matter. Higher up the chain you have been protected

Answer (score 0):

The compiler checks the access, and gives a compilation error, if the base class is inaccessible.   There is no need to emit different code to the executable.

There are cases where different code may be emitted (e.g. use of RTTI, `dynamic_cast`, etc which do runtime type checks) but you're not using that in this case.

Incidentally,

```
B* ptr = new D;
```

can be performed in a function that is a member or `friend` of `D`.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. You certainly  *can* create objects:

```
D* pd = new D;
```

You *can't*, however, *cast* a `D` object to the base `B` type, because of its 'private' scope.
You can see it, for example, with this code:

```
D d;             // created successfully
B *pd = & d;     // forbidden
B &pb = d;       // forbidden
```

The messages are clear:

```
'type cast' : conversion from 'D *' to 'B *' exists, but is inaccessible
'type cast' : conversion from 'D *' to 'B &' exists, but is inaccessible
```

which means object `D d` exists and it *can* be seen as type `B`, it just can not be accessed in this context.

That's why you do not see any difference in assembly: operations which are allowed, look the same in both cases, what's different is that some operations are *not allowed*.